# google colab GPU processing become very slow after keras and tensorflow upgrade

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I've upgrade my tensorflow and keras with this code:

`!pip install tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview`

Now every epoch of model learning cost 22 min which was 17 sec before this upgrade!!!
I did downgrade tensorflo and keras but it did not help!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your backend using the Runtime -> Reset all runtimes... menu item. (This is much faster than `kill -9 -1`, which will take some time to reconnect.)

Answer (score -1):

Ok. It's solved.
just restore everything in colab by this code:

```
kill -9 -1
```